# Getting error from implementing Try/Except

Tags: python

I am trying to add a try/except to my guessing game for non numerical entries from the user. Im not really sure how to implement it with my code but I did try but got an error saying:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'v'

I am not sure how to rearrange my code to get it to work with the try/except.

```py
def guessing_game(secret_number: int, user_guess: int):
   num_tries: int = 0
   user_name: str = input("Please enter your name: ")
   print(f"Hello {user_name}, i am thinking of a number between 1 and 20")
   secret_number: int = randint(1, 19)
   user_guess: int = int(input("Guess what it is: "))

   try:
      while num_tries != 5:
         if user_guess > secret_number:
            user_guess = int(input("Your guess is too high. Try again: "))
         elif user_guess < secret_number:
            user_guess = int(input("Your guess is too low. Try again: "))
         else:
            print(f"Congrats {user_name}, {secret_number} was the number i was thinking of")
            break
         num_tries += 1
      if user_guess != secret_number and num_tries == 5:
         print(f"Sorry.The number I was thinking of was {secret_number}")

   except ValueError:
      print("Error, value must be numerical")

guessing_game(2, 8)
```

Comment: Any code whose errors you want to catch must be *inside* the `try`. `user_guess: int = int(input("Guess what it is: "))` is not inside the `try`, so if that's what's throwing, the `try` will never see it.

Comment: Which particular line gives that error? Maybe that helps pinning the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this. No need to wrap everything in a function here (you weren't using the two arguments you passed in anyway).

- The outer `for` loop handles stopping the game once all attempts are exhausted; Python's (quite unique) `for`/`else` structure handles losing the game.
- The inner `while` loop loops for as long as the user is giving invalid input; you could add `if not (1 <= user_guess <= 19): raise ValueError()` in there to also have validation for whether the user is being silly and entering e.g. `-1` or `69`.
- To simplify things, there's only one `input()` any more, and the game loop modifies the `prompt` for it.

```
from random import randint

user_name: str = input("Please enter your name: ")
print(f"Hello {user_name}, i am thinking of a number between 1 and 20")
secret_number: int = randint(1, 19)
prompt = "Guess what it is: "
for num_tries in range(5):
    while True:
        try:
            user_guess: int = int(input(prompt))
            break  # out of the while
        except ValueError:
            print("Error, value must be numerical")

    if user_guess > secret_number:
        prompt = "Your guess is too high. Try again: "
    elif user_guess < secret_number:
        prompt = "Your guess is too low. Try again: "
    else:
        print(f"Congrats {user_name}, {secret_number} was the number i was thinking of")
        break
else:  # for loop was not `break`ed out of
    print(f"Sorry. The number I was thinking of was {secret_number}")
```

Comment: for the if not (1 <= user_guess <= 19): raise ValueError(), do I place it under the try block? because there is already a except ValueError: there so im not sure where that should be

Comment: Within the inner try block, before the `break`, yes. The idea would be to manually raise a value error that the `except` would catch.

Answer (score 0):

## Error explanation:

You are not correctly catching the exception because the input casting is outside the `try` block.

When user tries to enter a literal string, the line:

`user_guess: int = int(input("Guess what it is: "))`

raises `ValueError` because that string is not int-castable and the instruction is not inside the try, meaning that the default `traceback` handles the exception.

Just move that line inside the try block

```
try:
    user_guess: int = int(input("Guess what it is: "))
```

## Code improvement:

That been said, you need to organize your code better. First off your function should just do the matching between user input and secret number. Then you would create the loop and call that function for each user input:

```
def guessing_game(secret_number: int, user_guess: int):
    if user_guess > secret_number:
        print("Your guess is too high.")
    elif user_guess < secret_number:
        user_guess = print("Your guess is too low.")
    else:
        print(f"Congrats {user_name}, {secret_number} was the number i was thinking of")
        return True

user_name = input("Please enter your name: ") # String casting is redundant here.
print(f"Hello {user_name}, i am thinking of a number between 1 and 20")
secret_number = randint(1, 19) # Why not (1,20) though?

# Here is the loop. It keeps prompting the user to enter a number and if the 
# input represents a valid integer the function is called to compair them.
num_tries = 0
while True:
    if num_tries == 5:
        print(f"Sorry.The number I was thinking of was {secret_number}")
        break
    try:
       user_guess = int(input("Guess what it is: "))
       if guessing_game(secret_number, user_guess) == True:
           break
           
    except ValueError:
        print("Error, value must be numerical")

    num_tries += 1
```